# why does asp vb call code behind function from ajax return 404 not found

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an aspx page, I'm struggling for hours trying to call a function in the code behind (vb) on an input event. It keeps returning 404 not found error like this:

```
POST http://localhost:51976/simulations/agios.aspx/getbnqlibelle 404 (Not Found)
```

my control:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tcodebanque" 
    name="tcodebanque" 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="" 
    style="width: 100px; float: left; margin-right: 5px; border: 1px solid #000; 
           font-size: 12px; padding: 5px; height: 25px; border-radius: 0px;"
    onkeypress="getbnqlibelle(); return false;">
</asp:TextBox>
```

my ajax:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function getbnqlibelle() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "agios.aspx/getbnqlibelle",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

my code behind:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> 
Public Shared Function getbnqlibelle() As String
    Return ("done")
End Function
```

I have actually tried everything from the internet (every solution), none is working, can you please help me out?

Edit:

Tried a different browser: same error

Comment: Fyi, you have `dataType` twice in the ajax call.

Comment: Otherwise looks like it should work.

Comment: my mistake, I removed one but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your URL in the ajax function to include the 'simulations' path.

> url: "simulations/agios.aspx/getbnqlibelle"

Also, use the browser's dev tools to verify exactly what network path is requested.

Comment: changed the url: still not working. the path in the dev tools is http://localhost:51976/simulations/agios.aspx/getbnqlibelle